# Discover the formula of a function using genetic programming in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, genetic

I have a dataframe in Python with the data of an unknown function (i mean, values of x and their correspondant values of y) i want to discover the formula that relates both variables using genetic programming in python, how can i do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 1) Find a way of representing formulas, 2) Define mutation and crossover functions for these formulas, 3) find a way of measuring the fitness of a formula, 4) let evolution do its thing. Perhaps this functionality is in a standard ML library, perhaps not. In any event, your question is a bit too broad.